# What notification system to use in a chat application?

Tags: android, ios, notifications

I'm developing a chat application using Firebase Database in Android.

I've already done the core (chat and user's list activities), but I have yet to do the notification system.

I wanted to implement Google FCM as I am using firebase, but I find an hole in it, as it seems that I can not handle at all notifications delivered to iOs apps that are not in foreground.

As found in the [Data notification documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages)

> On iOS, FCM stores the message and delivers it only when the app is in the foreground and has established a FCM connection. On Android, a client app receives a data message in onMessageReceived() and can handle the key-value pairs accordingly.

And I need to catch the data notification even when the app is in background, I need that specifically because I want to update my badge counter on the app icon to let the user know how many unread messages he has.

I'm now tryng the [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com) solution can receive notification even when in background, it's free and interfaces with GCM. I'm sad to not stay with Google but if I can't update the badge count using FCM I have to look to an other side.

Any consideration will be appreciated.

Comment: But OneSignal has the exact same restrictions, as this is not Google's fault, but an Apple design decision. Up until iOS 9 you can't handle received remote notifications in background at all. Only in the new iOS 10 Apple has allowed it. Also, the badge is updated automatically by the system when a notification arrives.

Comment: **[Receiving Notifications](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-native-sdk#section--oshandlenotificationreceivedblock-)**
_OSHandleNotificationReceivedBlock_
Called when the app receives a notification. Note: This is called when your app is in focus only. **If you need this to be called when your app is in the background to set content_available to true when you send your notification.** - 
I just need to use the feature for badge counting if fcm provides this by default I can stay with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for get badge from server when app is in background or not running because your FirebaseMessagingService is running.

If you have any doubts regarding show badge on app icon than comment it because just yesterday i did show badge on app icon.

```
public class Custom_FirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMsgService";
    //private Activity strPushClickDesti;
    String activityName;

    @Override
    public void zzm(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("uniqbadge", "zzm");
        Set<String> keys = intent.getExtras().keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            try {
                 Log.i("uniq", " " + key + " " + intent.getExtras().get(key));
                if (key.equals("badge")) {
                    String cnt = intent.getExtras().get(key).toString();
                    int badgeCount = Integer.valueOf(cnt);
                    Log.i("uniq", " badge count " + badgeCount);
                    ShortcutBadger.applyCount(this, badgeCount);
                    Log.i("uniq", " " + "end");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("uniqbadge", "zzm Custom_FirebaseMessagingService" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        super.zzm(intent);
    }
```

Comment: What exactly zzz() method does?

Answer (score 0):

There is in fact a feature explored by OneSignal to achieve this behavior. It is the `content-available` value in the [notification payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW2). The good news is that is native to iOS 7 and above. So if you can customize the payload in FCM, it is possible. Just activate `remote-notification` in [background modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) and handle the badge update in [`application(didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application) and you are good to go.